# Search windows, returns filepath

Tags: excel, vba, windows, search

OK, so I have code that will take the data entered in "A3" and open a widows search with "*" + A3's contents. What I need now is when any file is found with that search to find the folder name that houses it. Basically we have prints stored by a random number not associated to the real part number but all the related prints are stored within this random numbered folder.

Example:

C:\Document Control\Master Prints***12345***\printxyz.pdf

If I were to search for "*xyz" and "printxyz.pdf" shows up, I now need the "12345" folder name to populate in a cell.

Here is what im using so far

```
Sub Macro4()
Dim var As Variant
var = "*" & Range("A3").Value
        Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & "search-ms:query=" & var & "&crumb=location:""C:\Document Control\Master Prints" & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Comment: When you call upon shell, it is not easy to get a return. I would rewrite the search in VBA, by doing so you would have the full path already in your [FileSystemObject](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/filesystemobject-object)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841250/return-value-from-vba-call-shellwhatever-cmd

Comment: You can use ADO to run your search via Windows Search: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62008062/478884

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar recently. I had words in cell `E1` that pertains to files in a folder. So I did an `instr` on the first 5 letters of that cell as my search then looped through the folder to find the file containing that string.

You should be able to adapt this code to what you need.

```
Const parentFolder As String = "I:\this\that\"
subFolder = parentFolder & getFoldPath(parentFolder, Left(.Range("E1"), 5)) & "\"

Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(subFolder)

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
    If InStr(oFile, Left(.Range("E1"), 5)) > 0 Then
        scope = subFolder & oFile.name
    End If
Next
```